# Convert ANY DICTIONARY type into table format in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

I imported table A to function B and each input is of any dictionary type. I am able to construct a table with the returned fields and the labels of the original records. It returned a large table, and I can get the expected result after doing the left join with table A. I also defined a udf B which can perform corresponding processes according to the record in table A, and return several fields to be added to the table. What I used is `ploop(B, A).unionAll(false)`.

However, I want to directly construct a table with the input of the ANY DICTIONARY variables in table A and add fields directly into the B function. How can I obtain the result in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the key of ANY DICT for the column name, please try:

```
tbl = table(0:2, d.keys(0, `INT`INT)
```

You don't need for loop for `vs` here, you can directly call `vs = d.values()` to obtain it when using DolphinDB.